# Responsive design not working at all in chrome/safari and possibly other browsers?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

So, the responsive css is being loaded correctly in IE / Firefox, but it doesn't work when I zoom in chrome or safari. It's just like the css isn't loaded at all.

The url is http://teothemes.com/wp/

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: it's working for me just fine in Chrome.. you should not zoom in/out but resize the browser window

Comment: works for me fine, except under like 500px width, it goes back to its normal look

Comment: ehm, still not working for me on safari / chrome..cleared the browser cache, history, still it doesn't resize, LOL.

Comment: Can't see the problem in chrome 20.0.1132.47 m on windows

Comment: What do you mean by 'responsive'?

Answer (score 2):

Plus, it's not responsive, just adaptive. B-)